# Create ANDROID.MK file from 2 android projects

Tags: android, build, projects

I have two android projects: a library and an application. Now I would like to create ANDROID.MK files which builds and install them. It doesn't really matter if it will build them separately, or together, I just need to get them into the phone software.

My problem is that the library also has resources. In eclipse this works fine, eclipse will create two separate R.java files and merge all the resources. But in ANDROID.MK file I can only specify the extra source files. How do I merge the resources as well? Or what are my options?

Here is the ANDROID.MK I currently have:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
    $(call all-java-files-under, ../MyLib/src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get this code in the Email app:

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, ../MyLib/res res)
```